# Libusb Windows MSVC Error : corrupted dll

Tags: visual-studio, dll, libusb

I am trying to create a program using **libusb library on Windows with Visual Studio 2019** (MSVC).
I am UNIX main, and little bit new in windows programming. So I may miss some easy issues.

First I **dowloaded libusb** on the official website : https://libusb.info/.
I extracted everything and opened the libusb-1.0.24\msvc\libusb_2019.sln project.
I **built the dll and lib** in all x86/x64 Debug/Release possibilities.
Any probleme with building the library.

I started a Visual Studio new project, with a single sample file (just display connected devices).
I added the include and a **x64 Debug dll version off the library**, same as the project.

But when I build the program, I have a **link error** :
*"[...]libusb-1.0.24\lib\libusb-1.0.dll : fatal error LNK1107: fichier non valide ou endommagé : impossible de lire à 0x348"*
In english : invalid or corrupted file : impossible to read at 0x348.

I tried to build with the static version off the library and I didn't had any issue. **The program works with my static build of libusb**.
I must use a dynamic link with the library for this project, so this is not a solution for me.

I also tryed to download directly the dll on the website : https://wikidll.com/fr/libusb/libusb-1.0-dll - **WARNING THE FIRST DOWNLOAD BUTTON IS AN ADD** - and I got same issue when running (the only difference is the corrupted line).

Thank for anyone trying to help me,

Leo

Comment: Linker works with .lib and not .dll file.

Comment: Thank, you !
So I must link my program with the .lib file that include the dll himself ?

Comment: You link with .lib file. Dll is used at runtime. So, using .lib file, the linker produces executable which requests Dll at runtime. During the build, Dll is not required, but when you run executable, Dll must be available.

Comment: As I sayed, I just started on Windows .I wasted so much time for a so easy error.
Thank you so much !